# Centering block in CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm attempting to center the blue box (c_container) in the middle of the page such that it always remains there (while retaining it's horizontal length) regardless of browser stretching. It seems to default to the left regardless of any attributes I throw at it.

The c_container will be used to display content, while the header will leverage a dynamic menu to transition from page to page. The final challenge is getting the box to stay put in the center vertically and horizontally.

HTML (clip)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
     <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
     <title>Page Title</title>
     <meta name="description" content="Write some words to describe your html page">
</head>
<body>

<div class="s_header">blah</div>
<div class="c_container">blah</div>
<div class="f_body">
    <div class="f_trim">blah</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS (clip)

```
p {
  align-content: center;
}

*{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
}

body{
  background-image: url('');
  background-repeat: repeat;
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 50px;
}

.blended_grid {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  margin: 0px auto 0 auto;
}
.s_header{
  background-color : rgb(180, 71, 71);
  float: left;
  clear: none;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;

}

.c_container{
  position: absolute;
  /* box-align: center;  */
  background-color: rgb(99, 235, 240);
  margin: auto;
  width: 960px;
  top:20%; 
  bottom:20%;
  /* height: 1050px; */
}

.f_body {
  background-color: rgb(35, 41, 36);
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  float: left;
  clear: none;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
}

.f_trim {
  position: absolute;
  height: 3px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(39, 240, 73);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this? CLAC calculation left-width

```css
*{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
}

body{
  background-image: url('');
  background-repeat: repeat;
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 50px;
}

.blended_grid {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  margin: 0px auto 0 auto;
}
.s_header{
  background-color : rgb(180, 71, 71);
  float: left;
  clear: none;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;

}

.c_container{
  position: absolute;
  /* box-align: center;  */
  background-color: rgb(99, 235, 240);
  margin:auto;
  width: 960px;
  top:20%; 
  bottom:20%;
  /* height: 1050px; */
    left:calc(50% - 480px); add this line
}

.f_body {
  background-color: rgb(35, 41, 36);
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  float: left;
  clear: none;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
}

.f_trim {
  position: absolute;
  height: 3px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(39, 240, 73);
}
```

```html
<div class="s_header">blah</div>
<div class="c_container">blah</div>
<div class="f_body">
    <div class="f_trim">meathead</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
p {
  align-content: center;
}

*{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
}

body{
  background-image: url('');
  background-repeat: repeat;
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 50px;
}

.blended_grid {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  margin: 0px auto 0 auto;
}
.s_header{
  background-color : rgb(180, 71, 71);
  float: left;
  clear: none;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;

}

.c_container{
  position: absolute;
  /* box-align: center;  */
  background-color: rgb(99, 235, 240);
  margin: auto;
  width: 960px;
  top: 50%;
  left:50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  text-align: center;
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
  /*   top:20%; 
  bottom:20%; */
/*   height: 1050px; */
}

.f_body {
  background-color: rgb(35, 41, 36);
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  float: left;
  clear: none;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
}

.f_trim {
  position: absolute;
  height: 3px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(39, 240, 73);
}
```

```html
<div class="s_header">blah</div>
<div class="c_container">blah</div>
<div class="f_body">
    <div class="f_trim">blah</div>
</div>
```